# How to use Rails 5.1.0 and jQuery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zurb-foundation

I started using Rails v5.1.0 which I understand comes without jQuery as a default, however want to install jQuery to work with Zurb Foundation 6.

What's the best way to set this up as foundation is not currently loading modals?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and their linked pages. Where did you search? Did you find any information? What did you try?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

## Summary:

- Install Yarn
- `yarn add jquery`
- Add jquery to application.js manifest file

~~~

I came across this problem today as well.

In [this article about using ActionCable with 5.1](https://medium.com/rubyinside/action-cable-hello-world-with-rails-5-1-efc475b0208b) I learned that the new way to get JQuery in your app is to use [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) which is a javascript dependency manager (Think Gemfile and Bundler but for javascript).

You'll notice a new executable file when you create a new app in Rails 5.1: `bin/yarn`. Trying to run this without yarn installed on your system will lend the typical helpful "what to do next" message:

`Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install`

- If you are using homebrew on Mac, you can simply `brew install yarn`.
- If you use Chocolatey on Windows, `choco install yarn`.
- On Linux, the usual "add a repo and `sudo apt-get install yarn` apply. I'll let you wander over to the docs page to get the details.

Once you're yarned up, you can do:

```
yarn add jquery
```

which will add jquery to the .js dependency file: `package.json`. This is kind of like your application's "Javascript Gemfile", and Yarn is your "Bundler".

Now that you've got jquery added to your project, you can include it in your manifest the usual way.

```
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

You may also find [this link](http://pixelatedworks.com/articles/embracing-change-rails51-adopts-yarn-webpack-and-the-js-ecosystem/) helpful as well. It's an article talking about the new ideas for handling Javascript dependencies within Rails.

Comment: Thanks dude!  Funny the 5.1 release notes say you don't need jQuery any more, but also don't say what to do if you DO need it.  note: I was getting the `couldn't find file 'jquery' with type 'application/javascript'` error

Comment: I discovered that my ajax requests would result in "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity" if I placed jquery after rails-ujs in my application.js file.  Putting the jquery require in the first position above and before the rails-ujs solved the problem

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit that. That sounds frustrating to diagnose!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the default jQuery from the javascript manifest file by removing the line containing `//= require jquery` from `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` and then add your version of jquery. You can add your jQuery file in `app/assets/javascripts` and it will be picked up automatically or using a CDN version.

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't appear to have resolved the problem. I believe jquery is loading but the modals aren't so maybe its an incompatibility with foundation