# foundation-rails 6.3.10 and rails 5.1.3 javascript is not working tap-bar is only displaying elements dropdown is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

[dropdown is not working. it seams java script is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXYTE.png)

I am using foundation-rails 6.3.10 and rails 5.1.3 javascript but it is not working. `tap-bar` is only displaying elements, the dropdown is not working.
It looks javascript is not working at all!

Do I have to include:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make this work.

First you have to add jQuery, [here is another question explaining how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43697023/how-to-use-rails-5-1-0-and-jquery)

Foundation actually needs jQuery to work properly. So, in short, you have to install yarn if you don't have it and then execute within your project:

```
yarn add jquery
```

After that add jQuery to application.js. My application.js file looks like this:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery
//= require foundation
//= require_tree .
```

Be careful to require jquery and foundation after turbolinks.

Next step is to create a foundation_load.coffee file. You can put this code in it to load foundation even with turbolinks around:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', () ->
  $(document).foundation()
)
```

That being done, you have one last thing to do. It seems that the file "foundation_and_overrides.scss" is not properly generated. If you look at it, you'll see that

```
@include foundation-drilldown-menu;
@include foundation-dropdown;
@include foundation-dropdown-menu;
```

Are imported before:

```
@include foundation-menu;
```

Thus, foundation-menu css rules will override foundation-dropdown css rules. Which is crazy as it should be the complete opposite.
So just put these imports after foundation-menu and you should be good to go. :)